# make an union using filterBy

Tags: angular, filter

using filterBy in angular2 app allow us to filter an array and I have figured that we can add 2 filters. However those 2 filters does not work as a union, meaning that for example if I set the filter `categorieFilter = {categorie: "cardio"}` and then I set the second one `materielFilter = {kb:1}` as a result I got all the value which have categorie: `"cardio" OR kb:1` or I'd like to have and union so : `categorie: "cardio" AND kb:1` in the same time.
I have tried to replace | by `&` or `&&` but does not seem to work...

```
*ngFor="let ex of exercice | filterBy: categorieFilter | filterBy : materielFilter"
```

Comment: Try `*ngFor="let ex of (exercice | filterBy: categorieFilter) | filterBy : materielFilter"`

Comment: Perfect :) Your welcome

Answer (score 0):

*ngFor="let ex of exercice" [hidden]="categorie!='cardio'&&kb!=1"